# Are there any good vb.net code repositories around?

Tags: vb.net, repository

I was wondering if there are any good vb.net code repositories around where people share code they have written, widgets they have developed, classes developed?  I hate re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: If you don't like re-inventing the wheel, why are you VB specific? I interpret your question as "I'd love some free widgets I can use", not "I'd love some source code from widgets, that I can learn from" :)

Answer (score 2):

### I've been to many places but I must say, CodeProject is the best by far. Their site is http://www.codeproject.com

IMHO, if you're really keen on not reinventing the wheel, I'd suggest you learn at least one more language.

I was stubbornly glued to VB and VB.NET until it dawned on me that  vb and vb.net aren't the only language in the world. I therefore learned C# and my programming life has never been the same.

I can now write code in all those 3 languages and am hoping to learn another, probably c++ before the end of the year.

The good thing about  being multilingual is that you're never limited in resources; if you can't find code to something in one language, you could find it code in another language. Plus, it doesn't stop you from using your preferred language.

Comment: +1 Yes, codeproject is the first place I look when I want to customize a control in some way. And I agree completely with learning C#, quite often you find things written in C# or VB.Net and if you know both it's trivial to translate (which can also be speeded up by the online code converters).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://www.getvb.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Visual Basic section of GitHub](http://github.com/languages/Visual%20Basic) (though you'll need to learn how to use Git before you get anywhere). You could also have a look at these search results on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?words=visual+basic&type_of_search=soft&fq[]=trove:453&words=&search=Search).